# Sometimes updating progress bar on main thread from worker thread doesn't crash the android application

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an example of android app to update progressbar on main thread from worker thread using handler, it's working fine but when i try to update progressbar inside worker thread without handler, it still works, though it's supposed to crash. Because according to Android documentation UI thread is not safe and must not be accessed from worker thread directly.

***Update
Sorry i put the wrong activity_main.xml.
This is the correct one i am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.riaz.handlerexample.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Update

Here is the activity_main.xml. ** Update. Wrong layout file, Please ignore

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:max="10"
    android:padding="4dip" >
</ProgressBar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Progress percentage"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="startProgress"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Thread thread; // work as a background thread
        Handler handler; // handle main thread messages from worker thread
       ProgressBar progressBar; // on UI/main thread


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnCreate Thread Name = "
                        +Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Thread Name = main

        System.out.println("OnCreate Method,Thread Name= " +
                Thread.currentThread().getName()); // Thread Name = main


        thread = new Thread( new MyThread());// creating a background thread
        thread.start();  // starting the background thread. it will execute run() method in
                        // MyThread class

       handler = new Handler(){  //handles the incoming messages from background thread

            @Override // receives message from worker thread sendmessage(message)
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                System.out.println("Inside Handler,Thread Name= " +
                        Thread.currentThread().getName()); //thread Name = main

               // progressBar.setProgress(msg.arg1);
            }
        };


    }


    // this is background / worker thread

    class MyThread implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Worker Thread Name = "
                            +Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Thread Name = main

            for (int i=0; i<100;i++)
            {

                System.out.println("Worker Thread,Thread Name= " +
                        Thread.currentThread().getName());

              //  Message message = Message.obtain(); // blank empty message
              //  message.arg1 = i;
              //  handler.sendMessage(message); //calling main thread

                progressBar.setProgress(i);


                //create delay to see the progress on progressbar

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: brother its crashed `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Comment: you are initializing `progressBar` from your main.xml but inside main XML it is `progressBar1`

Comment: @akhilesh0707 Yes you are right, some times it crashes and some time does not. Once it crashes it continue crashing after editing the code but once i restart android studio and emulator and run it again, then it works fine and continue to work fine, unless i change the code and restart the android studio and emulator.

Comment: @akhilesh0707 again you are right, i pasted the wrong layout xml file. please see the correct updated xml file.

Comment: Disable instant run and try and try it will crash everytime

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How to disable instant run? please....

Comment: goto >File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Intant Run> Remove Checkmark on Enable instant run to hot swap

Comment: let me now its worked or not

Comment: goto >File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment> after that i can't find Instant Run.... i can see only Build Tools, compiler, Coverage etc, i checked them all but couldn't find instant run any where

Comment: I am using android studio 2.3.1

Comment: did you follow my above file>setting steps?

Comment: yes, i did try that

Comment: Thanks for your help, Finally i found the answer... the culprit is progress bar. When i tried to update textview on UI from worker thread, it crashed as expected.  Thanks to  CommonsWare, for his comment to another question.
"Nowadays, ProgressBar has logic that allows setProgress() to be called on a background thread. It checks to see what thread you are on and does its own post() of a Runnable if needed. You can see this in the source code.
answered Jan 8 '13 at 17:41
CommonsWare

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220883/accessing-ui-view-in-another-thread-does-not-cause-a-crash-why

Comment: yes please post it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) answer on [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220883/accessing-ui-view-in-another-thread-does-not-cause-a-crash-why)

Nowadays, `ProgressBar` has logic that allows `setProgress()` to be called on a background thread. It checks to see what thread you are on and does its own `post()` of a `Runnable` if needed.

Answer reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220941/1548824)